# checking a workflow completion column in a workflow

Tags: workflow

Ive created an approval workflow that works fine.  I have a send workflow that will move the document to the recycle bin if its rejected.  Im my workflow i specified that if the column = "rejected" then delete.  However my condition doesnt seem to work.  I used caml builder to check the value of this column and ive noticed its not a string value but an integer.  In this case its 16 for approved and 17 for rejected.  I can easily change my second workflow to use this value but i was wondering why this is like that and if its reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats how it's been designed,

When you want to filter a document library or list using the workflow status, entering Completed or Pending into the Filter by field doesn’t work, all the statuses are stored as a integer, below are the codes I have come across and tested so far:

• NotStarted = 0

• FailedOnStart = 1

• InProgress = 2

• ErrorOccurred = 3

• StoppedByUser = 4

• Completed = 5

• FailedOnStartRetrying = 6

• ErrorOccurredRetrying = 7

• ViewQueryOverflow = 8

• Canceled = 15

• Approved = 16

• Rejected = 17

[Source](http://geekswithblogs.net/simonh/archive/2013/04/12/sharepoint-2010-workflow-status-values.aspx)

Comment: There are more numbers added for any custom status messages as well. I believe this is set up so that you can change the status message without breaking previously ran workflows.